# Layout responsivel com imagem

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Eu tenho uma área com um titulo, texto , lista e imagem.
Preciso deixar a imagem ao lado da área de texto, como na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao diminuir a resolução da tela eu preciso que a imagem fique logo após o titulo, ou seja, entra o titulo e o texto. E não no final dos textos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="text_content">
    <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>

    <div class="texto_Um">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat nam
      numquam provident repellat natus magni nemo at, porro unde non, totam,
      dolorem voluptates expedita? Ut aspernatur quibusdam molestiae cupiditate
      nihil.
    </div>

    <div class="texto_Dois">
      Alorem voluptates expedita? Ut aspernatur quibusdam molestiae cupiditate
      nihil.
    </div>

    <div class="lista_section">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi sed
          quod
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi sed
          quod
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi sed
          quod at laudantium quisquam voluptatem illo odio aperiam illum enim
          sit at laudantium quisquam voluptatem illo odio aperiam illum enim sit
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagem_section">
    <img
      src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/80/94/3kEq8V.jpeg"
      alt="teste"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.content{
    display: flex;   
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* background-color: #EFF0E8; */
}

.text_content {
    margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
    flex:1;
}

.texto_Dois, .lista_section{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

img{
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [@media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) do css para a responsividade. E, basicamente, usar o `display flex` para alinhar a imagem com o texto sempre que a tela do dispositivo for maior que 500px (ou a medida que vc deseja usar).

```css
.content{
    display: flex;   
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* background-color: #EFF0E8; */
}

.text_content {
    margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
    flex:1;
}

.texto_Dois, .lista_section{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

img{
    width: 400px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .content {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="text_content">
    <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>

    <div class="texto_Um">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat nam
      numquam provident repellat natus magni nemo at, porro unde non, totam,
      dolorem voluptates expedita? Ut aspernatur quibusdam molestiae cupiditate
      nihil.
    </div>

    <div class="texto_Dois">
      Alorem voluptates expedita? Ut aspernatur quibusdam molestiae cupiditate
      nihil.
    </div>

    <div class="lista_section">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi sed
          quod
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi sed
          quod
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi sed
          quod at laudantium quisquam voluptatem illo odio aperiam illum enim
          sit at laudantium quisquam voluptatem illo odio aperiam illum enim sit
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagem_section">
    <img
      src="https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/80/94/3kEq8V.jpeg"
      alt="teste"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```